# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: redirect, https

I was pleasantly surprised to see that CloudFlare had started providing a free SSL certificate to all its users, [my site](https://historyofrappelz.com) included.

I use a WordPress plugin to force HTTPS SSL on my pages, but the site is still accessible by HTTP, which leads to display issues. I want to force the native HTTP redirection to HTTPS in my .htaccess, but when I tried a redirect, I came across an infinite redirection loop.

How can I solve this?

Comment: I havent solution to my problem =/ Up :)

Comment: The directions here about [WordPress redirect loops](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/203487280--How-do-I-fix-the-infinite-redirect-loop-error-after-enabling-Flexible-SSL-with-WordPress-) might help (gleaned from other users that had the same issue).

Comment: [This helped me, better explanations.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29029049/best-practice-301-redirect-http-to-https-standard-domain)

Comment: [This helped me, better explanations.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29029049/best-practice-301-redirect-http-to-https-standard-domain)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering this old question, as it still remains unanswered. Instead of using the plugin, you should use cPanel to redirect HTTP to HTTPS. It will help you to get rid of the infinite redirection loop issue. Follow these steps:

1. Login to your cPanel account.
2. Click on the **File Manager**.
3. Ensure that public_html directory is being displayed. Scroll
   down and search for the .htaccess file. If you don't see the file,
   head to Settings at the top-right corner. Then check the box to show
   hidden files for document root.
4. Next, a pop up box will appear. Click on the **Edit** button to confirm
   encoding.
5. A new tab will show up. It will contain the codes of .htaccess. Copy
   and pasted this code to .htaccess file:

   ```
   RewriteEngineOn
   RewriteCond%{HTTPS}off
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
   ```
6. Finally, save the changes.

You can find more information about these steps [here](https://hostadvice.com/how-to/how-to-force-ssl-and-manage-the-non-ssl-page-using-cpanel/).

If you see mixed content and face trouble with the redirection, you will have to use [Really Simple SSL](https://wordpress.org/plugins/really-simple-ssl/) plugin. It will fix the issue completely.

Answer (score -1):

Put this code in `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Why? Please add an explanation to your answer.

Comment: An answer without any form of eplanation is quite useless. Where should the code go, what does it do, how does it work. File an [edit] with these requirements